# "az acr build" Azure CLI command, is there an equivalent Powershell cmdlet command?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I was searching for Azure Powershell cmdlet command that is equivalent to Azure CLI command that builds docker image, e.g.
**az acr build --registry $ACR_NAME --image helloacrtasks:v1 .**

I also could not find Powershell cmdlet for 'az acr repository list' CLI command

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-powershell) help?

Comment: The detail at the link refers to using docker commands that I know can be used to build docker e.g. docker build. However it does not have any 'az acr build' equivalent PowerShell command. I am wondering if any such PowerShell command even exists because I am unable to find it

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is the right place to ask for this.